# Получение всех стим id и ников с игрового сервера (python)

Tags: python, steam, steam-web-api

Я недавно начал изучать python, решил сделать дискорд бота. В общем для него мне нужно каким-то образом получить список стим id людей на сервере, я смог получить ники с a2s.players() из библиотеки a2s, но нигде вообще не могу найти как получить именно id. Может у кого-то есть какие-то догадки как это можно сделать или кто-то точно знает?

Comment: Если недавно изучаете Python, то может лучше доучить всё основное и работу с процессами и потоками, а потом начать изучать сторонные библиотеки типа для дискорд ботов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use A2S_INFO query to receive server's steamid.

- https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries

Then use GetFriendCount and GetFriendFromSourceByIndex functions to get steamid of the users (steamid in the parameter is server's steamid).

- https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamFriends

Информацию нашел на этом форуме
https://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1443408 (Автор - Zaczero)